# How to download already save image in yii framework

Tags: yii

I am using

```
$this->widget(
    'CMultiFileUpload',
    array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'Image',
        'accept' => 'jpg|gif|png|doc|docx|pdf',
        'denied' => 'Only doc,docx,pdf and txt are allowed', 
        'max' => 4,
        'remove' => '[x]',
        'duplicate'=>'Already Selected',
    )
);
```

for upload multiple images , i save all images into database.But i want to download that saved image.

```
public function uploadMultifile ($model, $attr, $path)
{
    /*
     * path when uploads folder is on site root.
     * $path='/uploads/doc/'
     */
     if ($sfile = CUploadedFile::getInstances($model, $attr)) {
         foreach ($sfile as $i => $file) {  
             $fileName = "{$sfile[$i]}";
             $formatName=time() . $i . '_' . $fileName;
             $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/' . $formatName);
             $ffile[$i] = $formatName;
         }

         return ($ffile);
     }
}
```

I want to provide link to image and download automatically.

```
echo CHtml::link($data->image);
```

Any help appreciated.

I tried

```
 public function actionDownloadImage()
 {
    $model = $this->loadModel($_GET['id']); 
    $fileDir = Yii::app()->basePath.'/Img/';

    Yii::app()
        ->request
        ->sendFile(
            $model->image,
            file_get_contents($fileDir.$model->image),
            $model->image
        );
 }
```

but give error..

Comment: Can you at least take the time to tell us what the error is, so we won't have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined folder path to save image in `uploadMultifile()` action. So you can't get your desired images from "Img" named folder. You have to make following changes in `uploadMultifile()` action:

```
public function uploadMultifile ($model, $attr, $path)
{
    /*
     * path when uploads folder is on site root.
     * $path='/uploads/doc/'
     */
     if ($sfile = CUploadedFile::getInstances($model, $attr)) {
         foreach ($sfile as $i => $file) {  
             $fileName = "{$sfile[$i]}";
             $formatName=time() . $i . '_' . $fileName;
             $file->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/Img/' . $formatName); // specify folder path where you have to save image
             $ffile[$i] = $formatName;
         }

         return ($ffile);
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.